# What is the correct use for "practised"?

Tags: word-choice, idioms, verbs

Which use of *practised* is correct, if any?

> I **practised** my singing.
>
> I **practised** at singing.
>
> I **practised** singing.

Comment: What is the difference between your first and third options?

Comment: Sorry... I asked this as soon as I woke up. A little tired, perhaps?

Comment: @JasperLoy Noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I practised my singing.

The 'my' is not technically incorrect, as far as I know, but is superfluous.  It would be difficult to practice someone else's singing :)

> I practised at singing.

One can *become practiced at* something, as a passive verb, but *to practice at* something directly is not grammatically correct.

> I practised singing.

This is the preferred usage.

Answer (score 1):

> I practised my singing.

I would use this if it's clear from the context what exactly you were singing. For instance a piece my teacher assigned to me or something I sing on a regular base.

> I practised at singing.

This sounds wrong to me. "At" should be used for the location you were practising at. I practised singing at school.

> I practised singing.

That's how I usually use it.

Comment: Don't agree about the first one: it doesn't suggest to me a particular piece. But it does suggest that the practice is particularly 'mine' - either something I do regularly, or something a teacher has assigned me. I agree about the others.

Comment: I agree with @Colin that including **my** implies the speaker already sings, or has at least just been assigned the activity.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, Colin and Fumble. I edited my reply.

Answer (score 1):

The are two words for the word practice.

- Practice - the noun form has a c
- Practise - the verb form has a s

Below are correct examples of how to use the two terms.

- [image: tick]I went to singing practice today.
- [image: tick]I want to practise my singing today.

*In one of your three examples, you used the word incorrectly.*

- [image: tick] I practised my singing.
- [image: cross] I practised at singing.
- [image: tick] I practised singing.

The usage of the word *at*, makes the word *singing* feel like a noun, which it isn't.

How is it possible to practise at singing? How is it possible to trip at walking? 
You can trip your walking? You can trip walking? But you cannot trip at walking!

The word *at* is a preposition, so it shouldn't be used in that manner, because prepositions are used for nouns.

Comment: The first part of your answer doesn't apply to the question. I already knew that stuff, hence the usage of the correct word *in* the examples. You haven't really specified if "at" is a correct usage or not, maybe edit your answer to apply as much as possible?

Comment: Actually, singing is used here as a gerund, which is a noun form of the verb. I am not sure if using **at** here is wrong or not, but if it is, I think it would not be for the reasons you exposed.

Comment: @yms Are you sure that the word *singing* is used as a noun? Mahnax talked about **practising singing** (verb) in the examples, as in the act of singing, not the place of signing (noun).

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I am not a native English speaker but gerunds are the same in many languages including mine (Spanish). Here is an example of "the act of singing" being mentioned as a gerund in a website about English grammar: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/gerunds.htm

Comment: I am from the UK, and I can tell you that the word *singing* is being used as a verb. The page you gave me is very confusing so I can understand your mistake. I know for a fact, that the word singing is being used as a **verb** and NOT a noun, because Mahnax is talking about the **act of singing**. Please look at my answer, where there are the bullet points that have 2 ticks in a row. You will find that the top one talks about the **place of signing** (noun), and the 2nd one talks about **act of singing** (verb). Place is a noun, and Act is a verb. You are wrong. Trust me on this.

Comment: According to M-W: Practice (with a 'c') can be used as either a verb or noun.   Practise (with an 's') can likewise be used either way, and is listed as an alternate form of the word.  In my experience, the 's' form is typically the UK spelling whereas the 'c' form is typically the US spelling.

Comment: I'm from the UK, and I'm using the correct form of the word. There is no such thing as a US way of spelling it. If you think so, people are spelling it wrong. It's a common mistake to make.

Comment: Both practise and practice are legitimate forms of the word according to Merriam-Webster and Dictionary.com.   I have seen my UK friends mostly use it with an "s", and in fact Dictionary.com lists the "s" form as the "British" usage.